# print file lines matching pattern recursively excluding multiple dirs (BASH)

Tags: bash, grep, find

I'd like to write a bash script to:

accept a REGEX to match. Find all files in current dir and eventually subdirs(if -r is specified) containing that WORD. Printing -n LINES after matched regex. Optionally: exclude multiple dirs or files by extensions.

an example:

```
./dir
    |- file_1
    |- file_2
    |- subDir1 
          |- file_3
          |- node_modules (subDir)
          |- bin (subDir)
```

running

```
myscript -w 'TODO' -r -d '<list of excluded dir>' -x <list of excluded extensions file>' -l '<lines inside file after where i found word to be printed>
```

it must be printed all the lines inside files that has TODO.

i'm using something like:

```
if [ "$RECURSIVE" -eq 1 ]; then
    grep -rw "./" -A $LINES -e "$WORD" --exclude $dirs 
fi
```

the problem is that i didn't know how to pass a list of dirs and files inside bash to be excluded by grep. I tried with regex

```
dirs="(node_modules|bin)"
```

but it is not read by grep.

**Another requirement** would be to print the data of last modification of the file

at the moment what i get it's simply:

```
./file1_path: line1
./file1_path: line2
...
```

I would like to get:

```
./file_path | last_modification_date | line_string
...
```

with the excluded dirs and files extension not being printed out.

I tried to complete this via find + grep, but i find hard to concatenate the commands. 
Now i'm stuck on this:

```
find . -maxdepth $MAXDEPTH -type f -exec ls -lah {} | gawk '{print "<here the infos to extract (filename data )>"}'\; -exec grep "$WORD" -A 4 {} \;
```

bu this creates problem in the piping with `gawk`, i get:

```
gawk: row com.:1: ./file_1
gawk: row com.:1: ^ syntax error
gawk: row com.:1: ./file_1
gawk: row com.:1:   ^ regular expression not complete
```

And no output for the second `-exec` command:

while without gawk it works fine:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 linux linux 2,4K mar 19 10:30 ./todo_checker  <=== THIS LINE
# Following program check search for TODO's in file your working on. 
# It is useful when you're a working on a large software and spread 
# TODO's over the files. 
#
# It check for TODO's and print: 
# file_name | file_location | file_last_modification
# n lines after todo
#
# parameters:
```

i would like to prettify THISLINE

Comment: If you are writing this for practice or something, that's a different story. But if you just need this functionality, [the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is really good at it and is easy to install on pretty much any OS. If you were to do it with it then, `--ignore-dir` or `—ignore` would have managed it all.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `find`.  It does pretty much what you list here.  Add a couple `| grep -v ...` to remove some results (your exclusions) and you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok thank you guys. Surely @Mihir i will have a look at the_silver_searcher . I tried to complete this via find + grep, but i find hard to concatenate the commands. Now i'm stuck on this: `find . -maxdepth $MAXDEPTH -type f -exec ls -lah {} | gawk '{print "<here the infos to extract (filename data )>"}'\; -exec grep "$WORD" -A 4 {} \;`   It works fine without the `awk`, but i need it to prettify the infos about file printed in command line